# IntelliJ won't let me use implement method as?

Tags: scala, intellij-idea

I'm trying to compile to following class in IntelliJ:

```
class QueryIterator[E](query: => E) extends Iterator[E] {
  private var n: Option[Option[E]] = None
  private def cache() = {
    if (n.isEmpty)
      try { n = Some(Some(query)) }
      catch { case _: Exception => n = Some(None) }
  }
  private def uncache() =
    n = None
  override def hasNext: Boolean = {
    cache()
    n.get.isDefined
  }
  override def next(): E = {
    cache()
    val r = n.get.get
    uncache()
    r
  }
  override def toMap[K, V](implicit ev: <:<[E, (K, V)]): GenMap[K, V] = ???
  def iterable: Iterable[E] =
    new AbstractIterable[E] {
      override def iterator: Iterator[E] = QueryIterator.this
      override def toMap[K, V](implicit ev: <:<[E, (K, V)]): GenMap[K, V] = ???
    }
}
```

But it just won't compile
[image]

It won't let me return null from these methods either.

I've tried restarting the sbt console, but it doesn't have any effect. I'd greatly appreciate help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error message tells you everything:

Your signature:

```
def toMap[K, V](implicit ev: <:<[E, (K, V)]): GenMap[K, V]
```

How the signature looks in [`Iterator`](https://www.scala-lang.org/api/current/scala/collection/AbstractIterator.html) and [`AbstractIterable`](https://www.scala-lang.org/api/current/scala/collection/AbstractIterator.html) (*)

```
def toMap[K, V](implicit ev: <:<[E, (K, V)]): immutable.Map[K, V]
```

Replace the `GenMap` with `immutable.Map` and it will compile just fine.

(*) In both classes, the method is inherited from https://www.scala-lang.org/api/current/scala/collection/TraversableOnce.html. Make sure to click on "full signature".

Comment: Thanks, solved the problem! The signature was generated by IntelliJ, so I have no idea why it was wrong.